# JDK11 + spring boot = JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath

Tags: spring-boot

I have a simple spring project based on the [official guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) to consume a web service. This sample seems to be targeting JDK 8 but I want to use the latest LTS, JDK 11.

I have adapted the `pom.xml` file and added some dependencies which seem to have been removed from the JDK, namely:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

However, I can't seem to start the application, I always get this error:

```java
➜  spring-test git:(master) mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault (SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:38)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault (WebServiceTemplate.java:830)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive (WebServiceTemplate.java:624)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive (WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive (WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
    at com.example.demo.CountryClient.getCountry (CountryClient.java:21)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.lambda$lookup$0 (DemoApplication.java:24)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner (SpringApplication.java:781)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners (SpringApplication.java:765)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:319)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1204)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main (DemoApplication.java:13)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
```

Although there are at least two questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916221/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-mo) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632086/java-11-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-module-path-or-classpa)) related to this topic, I've tried all combinations of versions that I could find in those posts and I still have the same error.

The specific JDK+maven version I'm using is:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T16:06:16+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.2/libexec
Java version: 11.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

And the code for my test is [here](https://github.com/edevil/spring-test).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869262/xjc-maven-pluginjaxb2-maven-plugin-java-11-migration-issues/56972713#56972713) and check if it may help you. We have a couple of projects using Java 11 with Spring WS and everything is working just fine. Also make sure that your `pom.xml` is targeting Java 11:

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Regarding the missing classes, we had to add the following dependency, and nothing else:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: My `pom.xml` is in the repository ([here](https://github.com/edevil/spring-test/blob/master/pom.xml)), I am targeting jdk 11 and have the dependency that you mentioned.

Comment: Instead of `maven-jaxb2-plugin` try to use `jaxb2-maven-plugin` 2.5+, which was mentioned on that answer. Only 3 months ago they fixed all Java 11 issues regarding those classes. The plugin you are using had the last update on May 2018, which most likely doesn't fix those Java 11 issues.

Comment: It turns out the error I was receiving was from the server, which did not have the jaxb dependency.

Comment: @AndréCruz THANK YOU! I tried run the server and the client
( https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/ and https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/ )
Thus I run into the same problem.

I try out to run SERVER with java8: ./gradlew clean assemble bootRun -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/opt/java/java8 and IT WORKS!!!

Can you add the answer in your question?

Answer (score 2):

we had to add the following dependencies

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

instead of:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

it is a problem for all versions of the jdk 11 even on amazone correto.