# Why does jaxb2-maven-plugin xjc fail with Corretto jdk11.0.15_9 but not with Temurin jdk-11.0.14.1+1

Tags: java, maven, xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin, corretto

Since upgrading my jdk to Corretto jdk11.0.15_9 the xjc goal of jaxb2-maven-plugin fails.
The problem doesn't manifest when running with Temurin jdk-11.0.14.1+1. I'm running it on windows 10 with maven 3.8.5.

Command:

```
> set JAVA_HOME=C:\Corretto\jdk11.0.15_9
> mvn jaxb2:xjc

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------< com.example >------------------
[INFO] Building example 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.5.0:xjc (default-cli) @ example ---
[INFO] Created EpisodePath [C:\Workspace\example\target\generated-sources\jaxb\META-INF\JAXB]: true
[INFO] Created EpisodePath [C:\Workspace\example\target\generated-sources\jaxb\META-INF\JAXB]: true
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.764 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-21T15:24:15+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.5.0:xjc (default-cli) on project example: "file:\C:\Users\johndoe\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-xjc\2.3.2\jaxb-xjc-2.3.2.jar!\META-INF\versions\9" is not a valid file name: {1}: Invalid file path -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have a bindings file here: `src/main/xjb/jaxb-bindings.xjb` and multiple xsd files in `src/main/xsd`.

This is the relevant piece of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- dependencyConvergence -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
            <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <packageName>com.example</packageName>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-Xequals</argument>
            <argument>-XhashCode</argument>
            <argument>-XtoString</argument>
        </arguments>
        <extension>true</extension>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Running it again with `-X` gives me the following stacktrace which makes me think something must have changed in the `java.io.File.toURL` behavior.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.5.0:xjc (default-cli) on project example: "file:\C:\Users\johndoe\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-xjc\2.3.2\jaxb-xjc-2.3.2.jar!\META-INF\versions\9" is not a valid file name: {1}: Invalid file path -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.5.0:xjc (default-cli) on project example: "file:\C:\Users\johndoe\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-xjc\2.3.2\jaxb-xjc-2.3.2.jar!\META-INF\versions\9" is not a valid file name: {1}
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:306)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:72)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: "file:\C:\Users\johndoe\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-xjc\2.3.2\jaxb-xjc-2.3.2.jar!\META-INF\versions\9" is not a valid file name: {1}
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.javageneration.AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.performExecution (AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.java:555)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractJaxbMojo.execute (AbstractJaxbMojo.java:337)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:72)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.xjc.BadCommandLineException: "file:\C:\Users\johndoe\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-xjc\2.3.2\jaxb-xjc-2.3.2.jar!\META-INF\versions\9" is not a valid file name: {1}
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArgument (Options.java:515)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver$OptionsEx.parseArgument (Driver.java:502)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArguments (Options.java:827)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run (Driver.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.javageneration.AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.performExecution (AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.java:475)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractJaxbMojo.execute (AbstractJaxbMojo.java:337)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:72)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Invalid file path
    at java.io.File.toURL (File.java:695)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArgument (Options.java:512)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver$OptionsEx.parseArgument (Driver.java:502)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArguments (Options.java:827)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run (Driver.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.javageneration.AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.performExecution (AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.java:475)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractJaxbMojo.execute (AbstractJaxbMojo.java:337)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:72)
```

Minimal reproducable scenario:
https://github.com/Crydust/so71956115

Comment: Can you create a sample project, so it's possible to test with similar to yours setup? The question is rather generic and it may be because of something is missing or because of the bug in JDK itself.

Comment: First question why are you using an old version of `jaxb2-maven-plugin`? 2.5.0 is of 2019... Using the most recent version....

Comment: @khmarbaise Version 3.1.0 generates files which import "jakarta.xml.bind..." and doesn't want to read my bindings file because of a namespace issue. I don't know how to deal with that. Then again ... if I can fix it that way ... trying it out now.

Comment: @khmarbaise I use org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics to add a equals, hashcode and tostring to the generated classes. This doesn't work with jaxb3 and I haven't found a replacement yet.

Comment: @khmarbaise it works if I clone the jaxb2-basics repository and do a `mvn install` on my machine so I can use 0.12.1-SNAPSHOT. Not an ideal solution.

Comment: There is "https://github.com/McBluna/jaxb3-basics", but it isn't available on maven central.

Comment: I'm using spring-boot in the real project and apparently they will only upgrade to jaxb3 in the next major version. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28635

Comment: I apparently CAN use jaxb2-maven-plugin 3.1.0, but it gets rather unpleasant. I need a local repository with jaxb3-basics. And that is before dealing with overriding spring-boot dependencies. https://github.com/Crydust/so71956115/tree/jaxb3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Switching to a newer version of jaxb2-maven-plugin required a switch to jaxb3,
but replacing jaxb2-maven-plugin by maven-jaxb2-plugin worked.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.14.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <argument>-Xequals</argument>
            <argument>-XhashCode</argument>
            <argument>-XtoString</argument>
        </args>
        <generatePackage>com.example</generatePackage>
        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Barry's suggestion (with some tweaks) works too.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <packageName>com.example.generated</packageName>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-Xequals</argument>
            <argument>-XhashCode</argument>
            <argument>-XtoString</argument>
        </arguments>
        <extension>true</extension>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62219797/375025 (adding JAXB dependencies to jaxb2-maven-plugin plugin) helped me resolve this issue, without having to change to maven-jaxb2-plugin

Comment: Indeed, if you want to keep jaxb2-maven-plugin in version 2.5.0, adding the jaxb-runtime and jaxb-xjc dependencies in version 2.3.6 was sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same issue yesterday. None of the above solutions helped me unfortunately. However, what helped was changing the version of JDK from Corretto jdk11.0.15_9 to Corretto jdk11.0.13.8.1. Clean install afterwards and everythign worked smoothly.

Comment: Maybe you have a different problem? Do you have the same stacktrace as I had when running Maven with `-X`? Have you been able to update your jdk since then or are you willing to accept being stuck on this version?

Comment: Yeah, I had the same stacktrace as you did. Fortunetely, this version of jdk was abosuletely enough for me so problem solved.