# How to specify input classes for jaxb2 in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, pom.xml

I am using the `schemagen` goal of `jaxb2-maven-plugin` to convert Java classes to xsd.
The classes in `com.example.entities` & `com.example.model` should be converted & the rest of the packages ignored.
How to do this in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>schemagen</id>
            <goals><goal>schemagen</goal></goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wading through really odd `FileNotFoundException` and `ClassNotFoundException`,
I discovered through [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869262/xjc-maven-pluginjaxb2-maven-plugin-java-11-migration-issues/54920934#54920934), that the `jaxb2-maven-plugin` has issues with Java 11.

Now, I am using **[jax-maven-plugin](https://github.com/davidmoten/jax-maven-plugin)** instead, which has simple configuration to include particular folders/packages.

In order to include classes `org.examples.models` & `org.examples.entities` only, to be converted to xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.davidmoten</groupId>
    <artifactId>jax-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>schemagen-source-option</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals><goal>schemagen</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                <sources>
                    <source>${basedir}/src/main/java/org/examples/models</source>
                    <source>${basedir}/src/main/java/org/examples/entities</source>
                </sources>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-d</argument>
                    <argument>${jaxb.generated}</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```